# How to use php curl to get data from multiple pages of an external website?

Tags: php, curl

i am trying to display articles from three different website on a single website. I know how to use curl in php. But the problem is all these three websites posts are listed with pagination. So when i try to use curl  to a url, it stop listing posts after reaching end of that url page. Is there any  inbuilt curl function which iterate through pages and list posts from all pages at one variable which i assign to curl_init()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is there any inbuilt curl function which iterate through pages` - no, there's not. you'll have to fetch each page individually with curl_exec(), just like javascript is fetching each page individually with XMLHttpRequest (most likely. could be iframes or page refresh instead, especially on old designs, but in this day and age, it's probably XHR)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Atleast i got something new(XHR) on which i can research.